# Does Array#sample guarantee random order?

Tags: ruby, random

Does it only guarantee a random subset, or also random order?

Use case is generating a secret string with `('a'..'z').to_a.sample(8).join`. I'd like to know whether I can trust that all 26⋅25⋅24⋅23⋅22⋅21⋅20⋅19 possible outcomes are equally likely.

The [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Array.html#method-i-sample) says:

> Choose [...] n random elements from the array.
>
> The elements are chosen by using random and unique indices into the array in order to ensure that an element doesn't repeat itself unless the array already contained duplicate elements.

I see three possible interpretations. For example for `[1, 2, 3].sample(2)`:

- Return `[1, 2]`, `[1, 3]`, `[2, 1]`, `[2, 3]`, `[3, 1]` or `[3, 2]`, each with probability 1/6. This is what you get when you pick a random element as the first output element and then another random element (from the remaining ones) as the second output element.
- Return `[1, 2]`, `[1, 3]` or `[2, 3]`, each with probability 1/3. This is what you get by choosing a subset of the indices and then going through the array, collecting the elements if their index is among the chosen ones.
- Something weird in between those two. For example return `[1, 2]` or `[1, 3]`, each with probability 1/3, or `[2, 3]` or `[3, 2]`, each with probability 1/6.

I tested it and the first interpretation is what happened. And looking at the source code, I also got the impression that that's what it does in general. But I'm worried that I'm overlooking something, or that that's just a side effect of the current implementation, and that it could change in the future (or already is different in some Ruby implementations). And I can imagine the second interpretation/implementation being beneficial, either because one *wants* such "stable" sampling, or for efficiency reasons.

Is my first interpretation what it's supposed to do? Can I rely on the result not only being a random subset but also having a random order? And shouldn't the documentation be clearer about this?

---

Here's my test code with statistics, in case you want to try it yourself:

```
array = (1..3).to_a
n = 2

count = Hash.new(0)
(10**6).times do
  count[array.sample(n)] += 1
end

puts "#{count.size} different samples occurred."
puts "Smallest was #{count.keys.min}, largest was #{count.keys.max}."
puts "Frequencies ranged from #{count.values.min} to #{count.values.max}."
```

Outputs for example:

```
6 different samples occurred.
Smallest was [1, 2], largest was [3, 2].
Frequencies ranged from 165698 to 167234.
```

---

Edit: I created a [Ruby issue](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/14147).

Comment: @engineersmnky Ruby uses Mersenne Twister, not C's `rand`.

Answer (score 3):

I expect the method's name derives from the way [samples are drawn *without replacement*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_random_sample) in statistics. In that context the elements of the population being sampled are not necessary ordered, and if they are ordered that has no bearing on how the sampling is done.

The usual way of explaining sampling without replacement is drawing a certain number of balls at random from a container, with each ball drawn being put aside before the next ball is drawn. The balls may be identified by color or number or in some other way, but the result of the sampling does not reflect any concept of ordering.

Keep in mind that the method `sample` is defined on the class `Array`, but the elements of arrays are not necessarily ordered. For example,

```
[1, "1", :one, 1..2, { a: 1 }].sample(2) # => [{:a=>1}, :one]
```

Obviously, the elements of this sample cannot be ordered.

It is conceivable that `sample` could have been constructed so that it would order the elements of the sample if they were comparable, but I cannot think of another Ruby method that behaves that way. Moreover, implementing that would be problematic. It would be easy to determine that the elements of `[1,2,3,4]` are comparable (using [Integer#<=>](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Integer.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E)), but it would not always be so simple. Suppose, for example, the array were

```
[1, 2.5, 3/2r, BigDecimal.new("2.1")]
```

These elements are in fact comparable (`[1, (3/2), 0.21e1, 2.5]` sorted), but Ruby would have to do some work to make that determination. I suppose Ruby could attempt to sort the sample and rescue the exception if the elements were not comparable, but that seems quite a stretch.

Comment: You misunderstood. I'm not asking whether the result gets ordered. I'm asking whether it gets ordered *randomly*. It's quite possible that it doesn't. That the elements *keep* their order. That the output is a subsequence of the input. You're talking about a different kind of "order". Arrays *are* ordered. *All* arrays. By definition. See the very first thing even Ruby's own [`Array` documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Array.html) says: *"Arrays are ordered, integer-indexed collections of any object"*. Or Stack Overflow's `array` tag text: *"An array is an ordered data structure"*.

Comment: I think I now understand what you are asking. In effect, your second interpretation is equivalent to randomly selecting elements from the array, without replacement, adding those elements and their indices to an array (`arr << [e,idx]`), sorting the array by index and then mapping the elements of the array to the values (`arr.map(&:first)`). Correct? (cont.)..

Comment: Yes, that's one way to do that. But I don't think it "limits the usefulness". If it were stable like that and you wanted random order instead, you could simply append `.shuffle`. Done. On the other hand, if it's random order and you want stable instead, that's not that trivial. So if it were stable, it would satisfy both the people who want stable and the people who want random order. Thus I'd say making it stable would *increase* the usefulness.

Comment: Having to write `arr.shuffle.sample(3)` would be more than a little confusing to anyone with any familiarity with statistical sampling.

Comment: That said, I right now want random order, and I don't want to append `.shuffle`. See the use case I just added to the question. I'm just saying one could argue this way that stable would be better, and I'm worried someone might do that and change the implementation.

Comment: Not `arr.shuffle.sample(3)` but `arr.sample(3).shuffle`.

Comment: Same difference: it would be confusing.

Comment: No, very different. How would that be confusing? It clearly simply says that you want not just a random subset but that you want it in random order. Do you think a `sample` method returning an array can be trusted to produce random order? Three or four out of the five algorithms *on the page you yourself linked to* do *not* produce random order but *are* stable or partially stable.

Answer (score 1):

When the documentation says "...ensure that an element doesn't repeat itself unless the array already contained duplicate elements," that sounds like a convoluted way of saying "sample without replacement."  If you sample *k* items without replacement from of a population of size *n*, the first element can be any of the *n* items with equal probability, the second can be any of the *n* - 1 remaining items, the third can be any of the *n* - 2 remaining, etc., up to the *k*<sup>th</sup> item.  That means you can get *n*!/(*n-k*)! possible outcomes, each with equal likelihood, which yields your first interpretation.

I agree that the documentation could be clearer, but wouldn't have thought to question that it was doing sampling without replacement until you brought it up.

Comment: Yes, that's how I would've implemented it and how the reference implementation does it (if I'm reading the source correctly). But maybe that's just because it's the "obvious" way to do it, not because that's the intended result. By the way, I think you're mistaken about *n choose k*. That's for my *second* interpretation, no?

Comment: @StefanPochmann Thanks for catching the error with *choose*, I should know better than to shoot from the hip when I'm trying to meet deadlines in the real world.

Comment: @StefanPochmann I think it's the intended result because the documentation is describing sampling without replacement, even if it's not the clearest wording.  If you agree that's what the documentation says, that's the answer.  If you don't, we're getting into the realm of whose opinion is right.

Comment: Maybe "choose" was your subconscious telling you that's what it *should* be :-). [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_(statistics)) and [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sample.html) also just say "subset". I interpret the part you quoted differently. I think it doesn't describe the *process* but just guarantees something about the *result*. That the output doesn't contain duplicates unless the input already contained duplicates. Anyway... I found something (see my answer), but maybe I should look for place more suitable for this question than Stack Overflow...

Answer (score 0):

Ok I now have weak evidence that random order is intended, from the reference implementation.

If the desired sample size `n` is small (up to 10), it [first creates random indexes](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/d209b4c0a2df0e20c65791bfe4dbdaccb76744fc/array.c#L4893-L4897) with shrinking range. For example for `n = 2` and an array of size 10, it creates a random index from 0 to 9 and then another from 0 to 8. Then it [increments the second index if it's larger than or equal to the first](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/d209b4c0a2df0e20c65791bfe4dbdaccb76744fc/array.c#L4912-L4916). That simulates picking and *removing* the value at the first index and then picking the value at the second index into the *remaining* nine values.

For `n = 3` it does the same, [possibly incrementing the second index and possibly incrementing the third index once or twice](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/d209b4c0a2df0e20c65791bfe4dbdaccb76744fc/array.c#L4917-L4926) (I think `l` means "lower" or "lesser" of `i` and `j`, and `g` means "greater").

For `n` from 4 to 10, [it still does the same](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/d209b4c0a2df0e20c65791bfe4dbdaccb76744fc/array.c#L4933-L4950), incrementing the later indexes as often as needed. But here it uses an extra array named `sorted` to keep track of the adapted indexes in sorted order (i.e., playing the more general role of `l` and `g`). **Now here's my argument:** It doesn't just store the adapted indexes in `sorted` but also writes them back into the `idx` array, and uses `idx` to finally collect the values. If random order wasn't intended, then it wouldn't have to do this. It could simply use the `sorted` indexes. And the many special cases suggest to me that the code is supposed to be optimized. So why wouldn't it use the optimization of using `sorted` and not writing back to `idx`? I suspect it's because random order is intended.